# how to use field.label as default value in a text-input

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

i'm using python, flask, jinja to make a form, i'm iterating through a list of fields to render the inputs, all is well.

i'm trying to use the field.label attribute as default value in the input boxes so that i don't need labels next to them, but instead of the actual label i'm getting (for a field with label = search_term)  `<label for=` inside the input, and `Search Term">` next to it...

if i place `{{field.label}}` anywhere else it correctly displays the field label, and if i use `field.name` as a value it works fine - why is it acting strangely only within the context of `{{ field (class="col-6 text-center", value=field.label)}}`?

thanks!

```
JINJA2
        {% for field in form if not field.name =="csrf_token" %}
        <tr>
          {% if field.type == "SubmitField" %}
          <td class="col-6 pr-3"> </td>
          <td class="col-6 text-left pl-3">{{form.submit(class="w-50 btn btn-outline-info") }} </td>

          {% elif field.type == "BooleanField"%}
          <td class="col-6 text-right pr-3">{{ field.label}}</td>
            <td class="col-4 text-left">{{ field (class="col-6 text-center")}}</td>

          {% elif field.type == "SelectMultipleField" %}
          <td class="col-6 text-right pr-3">What are you searching for? <br /><span class="small"> ctrl-click for multiple </span></td>
          <td class="text-left pl-3">{{ field(class="col-6 text-center") }}</td>

          {% else %}
          <td class="col-6 text-right pr-3">{{ field.label }}</td>
          <td class="col-6 text-left">{{ field (class="col-6 text-center", value=field.label)}}</td>
          {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

[image: form output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ field (class="col-6 text-center", value=field.label)}}
```

The reason for the broken result with the above code is that `field.label` by itself stringifies to HTML code, not just the text. You're trying to include HTML (including quotes) as the value in The generated HTML would be broken look something like:

```html
<input value="<label for="search">"> <!-- Invalid HTML! -->
```

From [WTForm's documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Label) we can see that the `label` has the `text` property, which will give you the plain text of the label.

Something like this would give you your desired result:

```
{{ field (class="col-6 text-center", value=field.label.text)}}
```

Also, are you perhaps looking for the `placeholder` attribute instead of `value`?

```html
<h2>Using 'value'</h2>

<input type=text value="Search Term"> Note that you have to delete the text first...

<h3>vs</h3 <br>

<h2>Using 'placeholder'</h2>

<input type=text placeholder="Search Term">
```

Comment: thanks!

and yes - i discovered placeholder after submitting forms filled with default values and not being happy!

but i'm glad to learn about the .text property. feels dumb asking questions that are in the docs, but honestly i'm only just starting to be able to make any sense of them at all!

Comment: No worries; at least submitting it as a StackOverflow question makes it more accessible for those using search engines (and everyday language)

Comment: honestly it's most a function of a foolhardy approahc to learning.. i.e. i'm not really nailing down anything properly because that's boring, instead i'm jugling python, flask, jinja, html, css, js, sql, github, docker, heroku/pas, etc all at once.... which makes a mess of the terminology in my head... property? attribute? parameter? argument? still though, i'm 3 months in and loving it! looking forward to giving back to the SO community when i have something valid to contribute!